# Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number pyspark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a script pyspark and got error:

> Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number pyspark**

Who can help me to solve this prob please?

[traceback--error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8lCq.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried this (removing `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` env var) ? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743

Comment: @baitmbarek thank you ^^ . I have no PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` defined ? which Java version are you using ? You need a Java-8 JRE.

Comment: I did this export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home and when i do **which java** in my terminal i got /usr/bin/java

Comment: Can you run `java -version` on your terminal ? Hope you only have one java version installed :)

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Would this be helpful ? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743#issuecomment-414919781 (installing findspark from conda)

Comment: i was following this link but it doesn't help . Thank you ^^

Comment: @baitmbarek please tell me if you ideas about how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
pip uninstall pyspark py4j
pip install pyspark py4j
```